# I want to send a form to another website using php

Tags: php

I've been trying to send a form my website to another website using this code

```php
$jumlah = $query1->jumlah;
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'url' => $url,
        'jumlah' => $jumlah
    )
); 
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://insta.kingdompanel.xyz/addlikes.php', false, $context);
```

Before I send it to that website, I'm trying to send the form to my own website, and it works. I change this code to try send a form there.

```php
file_get_contents('http://insta.kingdompanel.xyz/addlikes.php', false, $context);
```

After I change that, it doesn't send anything.

update :
here is it the network tab 
[image]

my goal is to post this data[image]

to this form which is different website, without opening this page[image]

Comment: Please go through the below links, you may understand better

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: so basically i need an authorization from the server to do this?

Comment: In the request header you can add 'header'  => 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' and try. It should work. Even after that request fails means, other server may be blocking it

Comment: Sorry I failed to understand what you are doing, I do not see any web server address anywhere

Comment: is the last row in my code are web server address?

Answer (score 0):

In the request header you can add 'header' => 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' and try. It should work. Even after that request fails means, other server may be blocking it

Comment: sorry if this question stupid, but what is request header? is it the <header> tag in HTML file?

Comment: In your posted code, **Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, this is request header. Based on the need you can add multiple header.

Comment: so after **Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded** i put ' , '  then add **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'**? 
like `'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$jumlah = $query1->jumlah;
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'url' => $url,
        'jumlah' => $jumlah
    )
); 
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'header'  => 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://insta.kingdompanel.xyz/addlikes.php', false, $context);
```

Try the above modified code, if it works fine otherwise, Other server may not allowing CORS requests

Comment: how do i know if the server not allowing CORS request

Comment: You can check in chrome developer tools -- Network tab

Comment: in name coloumn in network tab i see bot file (the file where i write the code) has no error cause it not red colored. but it still doesnt work

Comment: Enable preserve log and attach screen shot so that I can understand beteer

Comment: i added the picture to the post